# can't sync gradle from android studio, but works from console

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I have problem building syncing gradle files with project in android studio. 
I have multi project solution. 
I use 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1', and gradle wrapper version 2.2.1
When I click sync button it say's:

Gradle 'gitrepo' project refresh failed

Error:exception during working with external system:

call stack from idea.log: http://pastebin.com/WDh6FUc4

I've tried cleaning project, invalidate cache, restart computer, remove .gradle folder.

I've also found out that when I run gradlew and gradlew build it works normally, so I assume that build.gradle files are OK.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Self answering but maybe it will help someone else.

My build.gradle didn't have

```
versionCode 1
versionName "1"
```

in defaultConfig section. Gradle itself didn't crash at it but Android Studio had problems there.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem because I had set up `ndk dir` in my `local.settings` as:

`ndk.dir=/home/tm/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle`

Make sure you have the `ndk-bundle` in your location, or update your `local.settings` by removing the `ndk.dir` location.

It works fine for me after doing that.

Answer (score 1):

My `AndroidManifest.xml` file was broken, and caused the same issue.  Seems Android Studio doesn't like being in that state.  Fixing the file solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me **File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart** did the job